# Jenkins Credentials Store Access via Groovy

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I have found a way to access the [credentials store in Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins-scripts/blob/master/scriptler/changeCredentialPassword.groovy):

```
def getPassword = { username ->
    def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials.class,
        jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
    )

    def c = creds.findResult { it.username == username ? it : null }

    if ( c ) {
        println "found credential ${c.id} for username ${c.username}"

        def credentials_store = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(
            'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider'
            )[0].getStore()

         println "result: " + credentials_store
    } else {
      println "could not find credential for ${username}"
    }
}

getPassword("XYZ")
```

But now i would like to get the password for the appropriate user which i can't do...

I always get unknown method etc. if i try to access passord etc.

The reason for doing this is to use this user/password to call git and extract information from repository..

I always get something like this:

```
result: com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider$StoreImpl@1639eab2
```

## Update

After experimenting more (and the hint of Jeanne Boyarsky) with it i found that i was thinking to compilcated. The following already gives me the password for the user:

```
def getUserPassword = { username ->
    def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
            com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials.class,
            jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
            )

    def c = creds.findResult { it.username == username ? it : null }

    if ( c ) {
        return c.password
    } else {
        println "could not find credential for ${username}"
    }
}
```

Furthermore by using the following snippet you can iterate over the whole credentials store:

```
def credentials_store = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(
        'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider'
        )

println "credentials_store: ${credentials_store}"
println " Description: ${credentials_store.description}"
println " Target: ${credentials_store.target}"
credentials_store.each {  println "credentials_store.each: ${it}" }

credentials_store[0].credentials.each { it ->
    println "credentials: -> ${it}"
    if (it instanceof com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl) {
        println "XXX: username: ${it.username} password: ${it.password} description: ${it.description}"
    }
}
```

And you will get an output like this:

```
[(master)]:
credentials_store: [com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider@5a2822be]
 Description: [The descriptions...]
 Target: [com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider@5a2822be]
credentials_store.each: com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider@5a2822be
credentials: -> com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey@38357ca1
credentials: -> com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey@47cf7703
credentials: -> com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl@739abac5
XXX: username: User1 password: Password description: The description of the user.
credentials: -> com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl@884a53e6
XXX: username: User2 password: Password1 description: The description of the user1.
Result:   [com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey@38357ca1, com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey@47cf7703, com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl@739abac5, com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl@884a53e6]
```

So by using the [appropriate class in the `instanceof` clause](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/) you can select what you need.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This works. It gets the credentials rather than the store.

I didn't write any error handling so it blows up if you don't have a credentials object set up (or probably if you have two). That part is easy to add though. The tricky part is getting the right APIs!

```
def getPassword = { username ->
    def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernamePasswordCredentials.class,
        jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance
    )

    def c = creds.findResult { it.username == username ? it : null }

    if ( c ) {
        println "found credential ${c.id} for username ${c.username}"

        def systemCredentialsProvider = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(
            'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider'
            ).first()

      def password = systemCredentialsProvider.credentials.first().password

      println password


    } else {
      println "could not find credential for ${username}"
    }
}

getPassword("jeanne")
```

Comment: Your idea helped me to think into the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! So mine was too complicated too! I like your approach that you edited into the initial post. Once mine returned the answer, I stopped looking for other ways.

Comment: @JeanneBoyarsky how to find it if it's in specific jenkins cred folder?

Comment: @airdata I don't know. I've never needed to do that.

Answer (score 14):

The official solution n the [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Printing+a+list+of+credentials+and+their+IDs)

> Printing a list of all the credentials in the system and their IDs.

```
def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
);
for (c in creds) {
    println(c.id + ": " + c.description)
}
```

Comment: this just prints the credential names and IDs, not the actual secrets, as OP requested.

Comment: You could add "c.class" to the output, which will show one of:
* com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl
* com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey
* org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl
* org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.StringCredentialsImpl
* com.browserstack.automate.ci.jenkins.BrowserStackCredentials
* etc.

You could then narrow down the query and output the field holding the actual secret (which differs bewteen each Credentials implementation).

Comment: An working example for UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl below.

def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
);
for (c in creds) {
    println(c.id + ": " + c.username + ": " + c.password)
}

Answer (score 7):

### One liner to get the value of a credential

Assuming...

```
def CREDENTIAL_ID = "<key_credential_id"
```

##### One liner to get a private key credential:

> See [ssh credentials implementations](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/ssh-credentials/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/sshcredentials/impl/) for methods to extract values

```
def PRIVATE_KEY = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().getCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain.global()).find { it.getId().equals(CREDENTIAL_ID) }.getPrivateKey()
```

##### One liner to get a username/password credentials:

> See [username password credentials implementations](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/credentials/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/impl/UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl.html) for methods to extract values

```
def PASSWORD = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().getCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain.global()).find { it.getId().equals(CREDENTIAL_ID) }.getPassword()
```

```
def USERNAME = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().getCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain.global()).find { it.getId().equals(CREDENTIAL_ID) }.getUsername()
```

##### One liner to get a string credential:

> See [plain credentials implementation](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/plain-credentials/org/jenkinsci/plugins/plaincredentials/impl/StringCredentialsImpl.html) for methods to extract values

```
def SECRET = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().getCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain.global()).find { it.getId().equals(CREDENTIAL_ID) }.getSecret().getPlainText()
```

This allows you to do things like injecting credentials into a docker agent:

```
def CREDENTIAL_ID = "<key_credential_id"
def SECRET = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getStore().getCredentials(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain.global()).find { it.getId().equals(CREDENTIAL_ID) }.getSecret().getPlainText()
pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile {
            filename "build/Jenkins.Dockerfile"
            additionalBuildArgs "--build-arg SECRET=${SECRET}"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to retrieve the credentials for a given credentials ID, the simplest way is to use the [`withCredentials`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) pipeline step to bind credentials to variables.

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword( credentialsId: 'myCredentials', 
                     usernameVariable: 'MYUSER', passwordVariable: 'MYPWD' )]) { 
    echo "User: $MYUSER, Pwd: $MYPWD" 
}
```

Comment: In the meantime this works in pipelines but the post was at a time pipelines where not that distributed and some people haven't used them..Nevertheless thanks for your supplemental information which might help other in the future.

Comment: This is definitely a way to go. This approach will ensure that secrets are not written in build log.

Comment: This is the approach if you need to use the credentials from within a shell.
However not useful if you need to pass them to another object - especially as `withCredentials` does not add  `MYUSER` or `MYPWD` to the `env` object.

Comment: @simon.watts `withEnv(["MYUSER=$MYUSER", "MYPWD=$MYPWD"]){ /*code that uses env*/ }`