# Jenkins mask passwords use in "Execute system Groovy script"

Tags: jenkins, groovy

im trying to undeploy/deploy an application to a Tomcat via jenkins using "system Groovy script".

For the undeploy/deploy i need credentials.
These i masked in the jenkins job via "mask passwords" (user and password)

Im not able to use these variables in my "system Groovy script" properly.

when i use the credentials in the script directly it works fine.
This is my "system Groovy script":

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()

//def user = build.getEnvVars()['user']
//def password = build.getEnvVars()['password']


ant.taskdef( name: 'deploy', classname: 'org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask' )
ant.taskdef( name: 'undeploy', classname: 'org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask' )

ant.undeploy(
    url:deployURL,
    username:"${user}",
    password:"${password}",
    path:deployPath,
    failonerror:true)

ant.deploy(
    url:deployURL,
    username:"${user}",
    password:"${password}",
    path:deployPath
    war:warfile)
```

Comment: forgot a "Hello" and can not edit it....so i add it to the comment. Hello and thx for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205665/jenkins-credentials-store-access-via-groovy

Comment: Jacob, thanks very much. This solved my problem. now i had access to the saved password and could use it in the job. Thank you very much once again. Best regards   - Edit: How can i upvote your comment as a solution for my question?

Comment: glad that helped! I think the best thing to do would be to upvote the answer I linked to and maybe provide a summary of the specifics you used to adapt it to your problem and post it here, then accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jenkins Credentials Store Access via Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205665/jenkins-credentials-store-access-via-groovy)

I used the solution from the link above in the following way:

```
def credentials_store = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(
        'com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.SystemCredentialsProvider')

credentials_store[0].credentials.each { ThisJenkins ->
    if (ThisJenkins instanceof com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.impl.UsernamePasswordCredentialsImpl) {
        if (ThisJenkins.username == "MyUser") {
            user = ThisJenkins.username
            password = ThisJenkins.password
        }
    }
}
```

later on i used the "user" and "password" for my deployment:

```
ant.undeploy(
    url:'MyServer',
    username: user,
    password: password,
    path:'/MyTool',
    failonerror:false)
```