# Jenkins credentials in script block

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

I am attempting to retrieve a value stored in Jenkins Credentials in a Jenkins file script block but am unable to retreive the value

The following block in my jenkins file works

I have a Jenkins file that sets an environment variable with a credential value stored in jenkins credentials:

```
environment {
    CERT_CLIENT_TH = credentials("stored.cred.name")
}
```

When I try to do the same thing in a script block I'm unable to retreive the Credentials.

```
script {
  env.CERT_CLIENT_TH = credentials("stored.cred.name")
}
```

when I check the output using these two methods using echo `"${env.CERT_CLIENT_TH}"`

When getting in an envrionment block the output is "****" as expected because it is an encrypted credential value.

when I attempt to get credentials in a script block the echo output is

```
    @credentials(<anonymous>=stored.cred.name)
```

How to I get credentials in a script block in a Jenkins file?

Comment: Use a solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73320079/2004186) if you want to get credentials outside of the pipeline

Answer (score 6):

As per this [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment), the `credentials()` is a special helper method supported by the `environment` directive. It therefore won’t work within the `script` block. The `environment` directive itself can be defined at the top-level of the pipeline or within a stage to limit its scope.

You might alternatively use the `withCredentials( …​ ) { …​ }` step as described [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials) to limit the scope of the credentials in your pipeline.